# Type casting in Kotlin using Mockito fails

Tags: kotlin, mockito

When I try to mock a Map (or Mutable map) in Kotlin

```
val staticParams: Map<String, Any> = Mockito.mock<Map<*, *>>(MutableMap::class.java)
```

I'm getting the following message:

Type mismatch: inferred type is Map<*, *>! but Map<String, Any> was expected

How can I create a Mockito mock class in Kotlin?

Comment: Why mock it instead of creating the map itself according to the test you want to perform?

Comment: The message you receive is pretty clear: you mock with different wildcard types. Use `Mockito.mock<Map<String, Any>>`